# Deploying Django project with Pyinstaller and Apache

Tags: django, python-3.x, apache, pyinstaller

I am looking to deploy a Django project to run locally on users' machines.

I've looked into what webservers can be used to run the project and as it will be running in a Windows environment only I have tried using IIS and Apache (WAMP). The Django project runs fine in the development mode (runserver). It also runs fine on both web servers when using an uncompiled version of the code.

The problem comes when I try to package the project using Pyinstaller. As this builds a .exe I have to change the way the web servers run the project.

In IIS this actually works fine using wfastcgi, I just make wfastcgi as the target of the Pyinstaller build and set IIS to run this .exe. However IIS requires a few additional settings to be configured and I've struggled to find a way for these to be set automatically so instead I've tried to use Apache.

As mentioned Apache works fine when just using the source code and wsgi.py. An example of what I have in my httpd.conf file is below.

```
# Apache httpd.conf settings
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Program Files (x86)/Python36-32/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd" 
WSGIScriptAlias / "C:/mysite/wsgi.py" 
WSGIPythonHome "c:/Program Files (x86)/python36-32" 
WSGIPythonPath "C:/mysite"

Alias /static/ "C:/mysite/static/"

<Directory "C:/mysite/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/mysite">
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </files>
</Directory>
```

What I need to do now is have Apache run a packaged version of the project and that's where I'm stuck. I have tried to build the project using wsgi.py as the target, the Apache services all start up but when trying to access the site is returns a page with '500 Internal Server Error'.

So my question is, can you configure Apache to launch a .exe file, rather than a .py file, for Python to run a web site?

Comment: Have you considered using Gunicorn instead? You could include that in your Pyinstaller executable and use it to serve your Django application instead. Then your users wouldn't need to also install Apache.

Comment: @Meshi did you ever figure out how to do this? I find myself in the same boat.

Comment: @nickvans I ended up using IIS in the end. The problems I was having was enabling IIS and setting it through programmatically but I found you can use Windows' DICM to do it all so worked out in the end. I couldn't get Apache to work properly I'm afraid